# Bundler: Gem Installation Error "The term 'bundle' is not recognised"

Tags: git, github, rubygems, bundler

This is my first time asking questions on Stack Overflow, and I was wondering if I can obtain some advice.

I seem to be having some trouble with installing the Bundler Ruby Environment by following the instructions on the website (http://bundler.io/). I am unsure if I lack certain software (one that might be Ruby specific) or if it is something else (I am currently using GitHub's Git Shell Command Line Interface. I do not have any Ruby software on my PC).

The only code I was able to get working was:

install bundler
git add Gemfile Gemfile.lock

Other than that, I get an error message saying:

bundle: The term 'bundle' is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet, function, scriptfile, or operable program.

If I'm not being specific, I will try to update this info to give you all a better understanding.

Thank you, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You will have to install ruby first. Because bundler gem dependents on ruby.

***Windows*** - If you are using windows machine you can use devkit to install ruby and dependencies. Download from here http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

***Ubuntu*** - If you are on ubuntu you can install using apt-get

reference https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.10

Comment: Thank you very much :) That helped a lot! :D